Estimate for a sum over an index set involving divisors
In Iwaniec's paper "Fourier coefficients of modular forms of half-integral weight" (Invent. math. 87, 385-401 (1987)) I came across the following estimate (7.3), which he claims to be obvious, that I don't quite understand. The inequality states that
\begin{align*}
\sum _{r \in \mathcal{R}} r^{-1/8}\tau(r)^2 \ll \tau(n),
\end{align*}
where $n\gg1$ is a fixed square-free integer, $\tau(n) = \sum _{d|n} 1$ and
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{R} := \lbrace r:L|r,n\nmid r, (r,n)^2|r, r|(2n)^\infty\rbrace.  \ \ (4.4)
\end{align*}
Here, in turn, $L$ is a fixed integer divisible by $8$ and $r|(2n)^\infty$ means that every prime divisor of $r$ also divides $n$. So far I tried to sum over a simplified version of $\mathcal{R}$ only using the last condition as it seems to be most relevant but only got that the sum is bounded by $C^{\omega(n)}\cdot \tau(n)$ with $\omega(n)$ referring to the number of pairwise different prime divisors of $n$ and a constant $C$. Rewriting the sum over $\mathcal{R}$ entirey seems to much more complicated, so I wonder what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Please give the reference to the mentionned paper by Iwanec.

I'm refering "Fourier coefficients of modular forms
of half-integral weight" (Invent. math. 87, 385-401 (1987)). To be more precise, the relevant definition and estimate are (4.4) and (7.3)

Denote $n=p_{1}\cdot...\cdot p_{m}$ (so $m=\omega\left(n\right)$). First, we understand $\square$. As $p\mid r\Longrightarrow p\mid n$ and $n$ is square-free, we must have $\left(n,r\right)=rad\left(r\right)$. Hence, the condition $\left(n,r\right)^{2}\mid r$ translates to $p\mid r\Longrightarrow p^{2}\mid r$. The condition $n\nmid r$ where $n$ is square-free, translates to $\exists p\mid n$ with $p\nmid r$. We relax the condition with $L$ to $4 \mid r$. Hence $$\sum_{r\in\square}r^{-\frac{1}{8}}\tau^{2}\left(r\right)\le\sum_{\left(k_{1},...,k_{m}\right)\in D}\prod_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\left(k_{i}+1\right)^{2}}{p_{i}^{\frac{k_{i}}{8}}}$$ where $$D:=\left\{ \left(k_{1},...,k_{m}\right)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}: \exists i\neq j\in\left[m\right]\;\mathrm{with\;}k_{i}=0,k_{j}\geq 2,\;k_{i}=0\;\mathrm{or}\;\ge2\;\forall i\ge1\right\} .$$ Note that $$D=\biguplus_{s=1}^{m-1}D_{s}$$ where $$D_{s}:=\left\{ \left(k_{1},...,k_{m}\right)\in D:\mathrm{exactly\;s\;of\;the}\ m\ k_{i}\mathrm{s\;are\;non-zero}\right\} 
=\left\{ \left(k_{1},...,k_{m}\right)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}:\exists I\subset\left[m\right],\vert I\vert=s,\;\mathrm{s.t}\;k_{i}=\begin{cases}
\ge2 & i\in I\\
0 & o/w
\end{cases}\right\} .$$ Then we have $$\sum_{r\in\square}r^{-\frac{1}{8}}\tau^{2}\left(r\right)\le\sum_{\left(k_{1},...,k_{m}\right)\in D}\prod_{i=1}^{m}\frac{\left(k_{i}+1\right)^{2}}{p_{i}^{\frac{k_{i}}{8}}}
=\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}\sum_{\left(k_{1},...,k_{m}\right)\in D_{s}}\prod_{j=1}^{m}\frac{\left(k_{j}+1\right)^{2}}{p_{j}^{\frac{k_{j}}{8}}}
=$$$$\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}\sum_{\left\{ i_{1},...,i_{s}\right\} \subset\left[m\right],k_{i_{j}}\ge2}\prod_{j=1}^{s}\frac{\left(k_{i_{j}}+1\right)^{2}}{p_{i_{j}}^{\frac{k_{i_{j}}}{8}}}=:\left(*\right).$$ Note that the largest $\prod_{j=1}^{s}\frac{\left(k_{j}+1\right)^{2}}{p_{j}^{\frac{k_{i}}{8}}}$ is obtained if we always pick the first s smallest primes. Hence $$\left(*\right)\le\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}\sum_{k_{1},...,k_{s}\ge2}\cdot{m \choose s}\cdot\prod_{j=1}^{s}\frac{\left(k_{j}+1\right)^{2}}{p_{j}^{\frac{k_{j}}{8}}}=\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}{m \choose s}\sum_{k_{1},...,k_{s}=2}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{s}\frac{\left(k_{j}+1\right)^{2}}{p_{j}^{\frac{k_{j}}{8}}}
=\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}{m \choose s}\prod_{j=1}^{s}\sum_{k_{j}=2}^{\infty}\frac{\left(k_{j}+1\right)^{2}}{p_{j}^{\frac{k_{j}}{8}}}=\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}{m \choose s}\prod_{j=1}^{s}\frac{4-11p_{j}^{\frac{1}{8}}+9p_{j}^{\frac{1}{4}}}{\left(p_{j}^{\frac{1}{8}}-1\right)^{3}p_{j}^{\frac{1}{8}}}
\le\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}{m \choose s}\prod_{j=1}^{s}\frac{5000}{p_{j}^{\frac{1}{4}}}\ll\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}{m \choose s}\frac{5000^{s}}{\prod_{j=1}^{s}\left(3+2\cdot\left(j-2\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}}
\le\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}{m \choose s}\frac{5000^{s}}{s!^{\frac{1}{4}}}\le\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}{m \choose s}\frac{5000^{s}}{\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)^{\frac{s}{8}}}\le\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}{m \choose s}\frac{5500^{s}}{s^{\frac{s}{8}}}\le{\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{5500^{n}}{n^{\frac{n}{2}}}}\cdot\sum_{s=0}^{m}{m \choose s}
\ll2^{m}\le\tau\left(n\right)$$ since $ 2^{\omega\left(n\right)}\le\tau\left(n\right)$ and $k!\ge\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^{\frac{k}{2}}$ for all $k\ge1$.
